# Dynamically construct select field in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select, linq-to-entities, ef-database-first

In my simple database first Entity Framework scenario I have customers that have price list numbers assigned to them. On the other hand there is a table of products that has 7 price columns corresponding to the price lists, e.g. PR_1, PR_2, PR_3, etc.

I want to make a projection of a few properties. The problem is that one of the properties/fields is depending on the price list number of the customer, therefor this needs to be constructed on the fly. So if the price list number is 2 then the property to be used is PR_2 and so on.

```
public IList<Product> GetSalesList(int customerId)
{
    Customer customer = this.customerService.Get(customerId);

    var products = this.productRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(p => p.ProductCode)
            .Select(p => new Product
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                ProductCode = p.ProductCode,
                Description = p.Description,
                PricingTypeCode = p.PricingTypeCode,
                Quantity = 0,
                SalesPrice = <<PR_ + customer.PricelistNumber.ToString()>> 
             }).ToList();

    return products;
}
```

I've read about DLINQ but I don't want to use that cause I think this is merely an exception.

Can anyone point me to the right direction or does someone a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would store all the prices in the `Product` and then make `SalesPrice` a method that calculates the sale price based on the customer's price list number.

Something like:

```
public decimal SalesPrice(Customer customer)
{
    return prices[customer.PriceListNumber - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this a good alternative but in my scenario the `Product` is a DTO. So this method will go in a service. Still I prefer to get the dynamic construction of a select field working.